# Query selecting wrong data when trying to group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

This *MySQL* query should return TOP 15 players of today whose score lower than 270. Every player can play many times, so It should return highest score of player. I can't understand what's wrong with `GROUP BY` or `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT userName, 
       MAX(CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED)) Score
FROM Game 
WHERE userName IS NOT NULL AND 
      CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED) < 270 AND 
      DATE(PlayTime) = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY FBId, userName, CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED)
ORDER BY CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT 15
```

`FBId` is unique for every player, that's why I'm unsing It in `GROUP BY` clause, `userName` can be equal if players have the same names.

P.s. Score is of type `VARCHAR` that's why I'm casting it to `INT`.

After using query above It selecting duplicate names in following:

```
Will Jason          227
Will Jason          226
Jessica Anton       219
Jessica Anton       218
Tom Edi             215
Simon Dougs         213
Peter Yang          210
Steeve Maclay       208
Monica Termson      207
Dave Stuart         206
```

That because included `Score` to `GROUP BY` clause?

---

But If I use following query (removed `CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED)` from `GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT userName, 
       MAX(CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED)) Score
FROM Game 
WHERE userName IS NOT NULL AND 
      CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED) < 270 AND 
      DATE(PlayTime) = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY FBId, userName
ORDER BY CAST(Score AS UNSIGNED) DESC LIMIT 15
```

It selecting also wrong (skipped some users):

```
Will Jason          227
Jessica Anton       219
Jeniffer Taylor     195
Tom Drugton         187
Monica Termson      207
Christina Queenton  183
Dave Stuart         206
David Tomson        170
Susan Clark         205
Sarah Lopez         188
```

Have you any ideas? Seems that first query selecting correct values just with duplicate names.

**UPDATE:**

Table structure:

```
Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
FBId INT
Score VARCHAR(20)
userName NVARCHAR(80)
PlayTime TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: What if you trying GROUP BY userName instead of FBId?

Comment: Could you share the table structure ?

Comment: userName can be equal of some player for example if 2 players have the same firstname and lastname It will select wrong data.

Comment: The easy to remember group by rule is: "List all selected columns that are not arguments to aggregate functions (MAX, SUM etc) in the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: So in this case why It working only with `FBId` in `GROUP BY` clause? When `userName` is in `SELECT` clause. I thought that I need to use `userName` in `GROUP BY` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select fbid, username, max(score) as thescore
  from game
    where score < 270
  group by fbid
  order by max(cast(score as unsigned)) desc limit 15;
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e2bc/9

Comment: I found this solutions by myself, but thank you for trying to help. I thought that in MySQL is the same as in SQL-server if I use aggregate function in select clause, should be grouped all columns from select clause.

Comment: Yeah it's a lazy-ism that leads to a LOT of problems for people who don't realise that it can quite easily choose wrong info to return for the non-aggregated, non-grouped fields. In this case it is fine because an fbid will always resolve to the same username